# Python script to run Hive queries

Tags: python, hive, hiveql

Can anyone please guide me in how to run .hql queries using Python. Tried Hiveutils lib but its not present in the dev environment. Any other way to execute the queries?

Comment: There's also ImPyla, that supports both Hive and Impala (which use the same binary protocol). Last time I checked, it worked. Which was not the case for PyHive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PyHive](https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive): PyHive is a collection of Python DB-API and SQLAlchemy interfaces for Presto and Hive.

Example:

```
from pyhive import hive
cursor = hive.connect('localhost').cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM my_awesome_data LIMIT 10')
print(cursor.fetchone())
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: Last time I checked, the "stable" version of PyHive was broken, even in Anaconda repos. You have to recompile the "latest" SASL libraries to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using pyhs2, try working like the below given example

```
    import pyhs2
    with pyhs2.connect(host='localhost',
           port=10000,
           authMechanism="PLAIN",
           user='your_user',
           password='your_password',
           database='your_default_db') as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            print cur.getDatabases()
            cur.execute("select * from table")
            #Return info from query
            print cur.getSchema()
```